# About presenter pattern in rails. is a better way to do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvp

I have in my model:

```
def presenter
   @presenter ||= ProfilePresenter.new(self)
   @presenter
end
```

The ProfilePresenter is a class that has methods like, get_link(), get_img_url(size), get_sex(), get_relationship_status() and other methods that have not to do with the model, not even with the controller but is used multiple times in the view.

So now i use them by doing this:

```
Profile.presenter.get_link
# or
Profile.presenter.get_img_url('thumb') # returns the path of the image. is not used to make a db query
```

Sincerelly i think i missed out the real concept of presenters.. but this is what m trying to archive, how can be called this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally this sort of thing is handled via helper methods, such as:

```
def profile_link(profile)
  profile.link ? content_tag(:a, h(profile.name), :href => profile.link) : 'No profile'
end
```

It is unfortunate you cannot layer in Presenter-style helper methods that extend a Model at view time. They need to be called in a procedural manner with a parameter, kind of anti-OO.

The Presenter approach is not fully supported in the Rails MVC area because it needs to bind to a view in order to have access to the various helper methods required to properly render content, plus information about the session that may impact the presentation.

A more robust approach might be to do something like this:

```
class ProfilePresenter
  def initialize(view, profile)
    @profile = profile
    @view = view

    yield(self) if (block_given?)
  end

  def link
    @profile.link ? @view.content_tag(:a, @view.h(profile.name), :href => @profile.link) : 'No profile'
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    @profile.send(*args)
  end
end
```

This would show up in your view as something like:

```
<% ProfilePresenter.new(self, @profile) do |profile| %>
<div><%= profile.link %>
<% end %>
```

You can simplify calling this by making a helper method that does something mildly crazy like:

```
def presenter_for(model)
  "#{model.class}Presenter".constantize.new(self, model) do |presenter|
    yield(presenter) if (block_given?)
  end
end
```

This means you have a much simpler call:

```
<% presenter_for(@profile) do |profile| %>
<div><%= profile.link %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a very nice approach. Clean. Are you using something like this now?

Comment: Is not easier to just use: "@profile.presenter.get_url" and it's ready to go? or it might be more compressed like: "@profile.pr.get_url". That because i dont use so much just in loops but other things so the use would be: "presenter_for(@profile).get_url"

Comment: @nathanvda I've used approaches like this with wrappers before, though even they didn't follow the Presenter pattern as closely. This is a technique for bridging the Model and View worlds.

Comment: Well, in silverlight you would use MVVP; and up until now i didn't see a real need to use a Presenter. But using a solution like this instead of helpers could be much cleaner. Feels more OO indeed. Very nice.

Comment: Having presenter pattern is needed when you have complex view for sure. This means if you have multiply models (db entities) needed to be presented in one view. Helpers are enough if you have one db entity or graph, and you are following MVC patter. as @nathanvda mentioned MVVP (which is actually MVVM pattern) it came from idea of wrapping  several models with ViewModel so it can be easily reused in other views. I like that approach, but haven't yet went to such need to solve view complexity with it.

Comment: ... another note. Regarding example above you should really consider using routing helpers, I assume you have profile_controller and profile model, wouldn't be easier to register those as resources in route.rb file and simple call in view <%= link_to "Your profile", profile_path(profile) %>. I found my self many times reinventing a wheel in rails, it was always easier use existing feature rather than implementing same in different lexical meaning. After all someone there on internet is managing code so you don't have to worry about if it will fit correct in next version of framework