# Best approach - Conditions in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model with attibutes name, title, description ect. If the name is by example weather-foracast I want to show an extra html element

```
= high_chart("my_id", @chart)
```

in the show template, wich generates a nice chart. When the page is not weather-foracast i don't want to show the chart.

What is the best approach? Conditions in the view?

Comment: did you read about layouts, partials, helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks really close to the Exhibit Pattern presented in [Object on Rails](http://objectsonrails.com/#ID-2656c30c-080a-4a4e-a53e-4fbaad39c262).

Simply explained, the solution proposed is to wrap your model in a decorator (or multiple decorators) chosen using the state of your model (in your case the name of the record).

I cannot explain it as well as it is explained in the [book](http://objectsonrails.com/#ID-2656c30c-080a-4a4e-a53e-4fbaad39c262) but that Pattern is so useful that Avdi Grimm made a gem out of it : https://github.com/objects-on-rails/display-case

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're HAML, you can just use an `if` modifier like so:

```
= high_chart("my_id", @chart) if [model.name] == "weather-forecast"
```

where `[model.name]` is replaced with the appropriate code.

Comment: @Remco, hope you wont get too many such `if`s in your views after some time

Comment: If you have to many `if`s you're doing it wrong and should consider refactoring. That said, the occasional `if` statement in a view is perfectly fine, so long as the conditional is used to determine the how information should be displayed. Even the examples provided in the Rails Guides contain conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is totally over the top, but something to consider is moving your conditional logic outside of your views.
Maybe going with the View Presenter pattern, see this:
[About presenter pattern in rails. is a better way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822314/about-presenter-pattern-in-rails-is-a-better-way-to-do-it)

Presenters are ruby objects and can be tested really easily.
Whereas having tons of logic inside the view is really hard to test.
Furthermore, you want isolation of logic, checking for model.name inside your view page is not the best way of MVC.